# what triangle inequality was used in this proof that distance between 2 cauchy sequence is cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

This is proof of the problem: If pn and qn are two Cauchy sequence in a metric space, then d(pn,qn) is a Cauchy sequence in R. Can someone explain how we got the first inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [reverse triangle inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality), which is itself a consequence of the triangle inequality:
$$\begin{align*}
|d(p_m,q_m)&-d(p_n,q_n)| \\
&= |d(p_m,q_m)-d(q_m,p_n)+d(q_m,p_n)-d(p_n,q_n)|\\
&\leq |d(p_m,q_m)-d(q_m,p_n)|+|d(q_m,p_n)-d(p_n,q_n)| \tag{Triangle}\\
&= |d(p_m,\color{red}{q_m})-d(\color{red}{q_m},p_n)|+|d(q_m,\color{blue}{p_n})-d(\color{blue}{p_n},q_n)|\\
&\leq d(p_m,p_n)+d(q_m,q_n) \tag{Reverse}
\end{align*}$$